# need help creating a batch file to call a list of networked servers and to find a file in each

Tags: scripting, batch-file

so i'm trying to figure this out and i don't think my scripting skills are up to par. :(

basically what i'm trying to do is this.

have a script call a file, the file has a list of members servers that i want to look through. i want to search for a file on each one of those servers and then spit out a log that lists that file's path.

so.. for example the file that is to be referenced is `text.txt` and within that file lists server 1, 2, 3.

i want to scan each server in this path `c:\temp\` all sub dirs and look for `file.exe`

then spit out a log that displays the server and its path location of `file.exe`

```
server1 c:\temp\dir1\file.exe
server2 c:\temp\dir3\dir5\file.exe
```

anybody??? :(

thanks in advance!

this is what i've done so far...

```
@ECHO OFF
SET FLNM=file.exe
SET DRV=c
SET DIRS=temp
IF NOT DEFINED FLNM GOTO NAME
IF /I "%FLNM%"=="/Q" GOTO :EOF
SET FLNM=%FLNM: =.%
:DV
IF NOT DEFINED DRV GOTO DV
IF EXIST RESULTS.TXT DEL RESULTS.TXT
IF DEFINED DIRS SET DIRS=%DIRS: =.%
FOR %%D IN (%DRV%) DO (
    FOR %%G IN (%FLNM%) DO (
        IF DEFINED DIRS (
            FOR %%C IN (%DIRS%) DO (
                DIR %%D:\ /L /B /S|FINDSTR /I /E \%%C.\%%G>>RESULTS.TXT
            )
        ) ELSE (
            DIR %%D:\ /L /B /S|FINDSTR /I /E \%%G>>RESULTS.TXT
        )
    )
)
CALL :ZEROBYTE RESULTS.TXT
IF NOT EXIST RESULTS.TXT ECHO:"FILES NOT FOUND">>RESULTS.TXT
START NOTEPAD RESULTS.TXT
EXIT /B
:ZEROBYTE
IF %~Z1==0 DEL RESULTS.TXT
GOTO :EOF
```

i can get this to run locally on each but i rather run it centrally.  also i can't seem to get it to look under all the directories.  if i list a directory, it only scans within that root only.

Comment: This seems to me to be a case for server fault. also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: please add it to your question.

Comment: lol yeah... i realized that after i copy/pasted it all in here =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `test.txt` is formatted like this:

```
server1
server2
server3
```

then you could do this:

```
for /f %s in (test.txt) do dir/s/b \\%s\c$\temp\file.exe
```

Note that you need to be a domain administrator to do this for remote Windows Vista/7/Server 2008/R2 computers, but for Windows 2000/XP/Server 2003 you only need to have local administrator rights to each PC.

Alternatively you could share the temp folder on each PC e.g. using `net share temp$=C:\temp` and then you could use `\\%s\temp$\file.exe` instead, then you would only need normal share and file permissions.

Comment: This is good. A domain admin will have access to your Administrative shares (C$, D$, etc) and this will do what you need :)